# cut box shadow of inner div to parent div

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a below effect in css/HTMl which is consisting of some random images at random place and ripple circles in center -

[image]

I have used box shadow for the center circular effect but the shadow is going out of parent square also.

below is my code -

```css
body{
  background: #000;
}
.ripple {
  width: 400px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top:40px;
  position:relative;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
  
}
h2{
  font-size: 24px;
  z-index:1
}

.inner{
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
   width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #ff8895;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 35px rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.2), 0 0 0 70px rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.2);
     border-radius: 100px;
  
}

.img{
  width:24px;
  height:24px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top:-10px;
  left:5px;
  background: black;
  opacity:0.5
}

.img1{
  width:12px;
  height:12px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top:35px;
  left:25px;
  background: black;
  opacity:0.3
}

.img2{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top:60px;
  left:5px;
  background: black;
  opacity:0.8
}

.img3{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top:15px;
  left:45px;
  background: black;
  opacity:0.2
}

.img4{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:55px;
  background: black;
  opacity:0.2
}

.img5{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top:-30px;
  left:60px;
  background: black;
  opacity:0.8
}

.img6{
  width:24px;
  height:24px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:90px;
  background: black;
  opacity:0.4
}

.img7{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top:60px;
  left:80px;
  background: black;
  opacity:0.8
}

.img8{
  width:12px;
  height:12px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:150px;
  background: black;
  opacity:0.4
}

.img9{
  width:24px;
  height:24px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top:40px;
  left:210px;
  background: black;
  opacity:0.4
}

.img10{
  width:12px;
  height:12px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top:20px;
  right:140px;
  background: black;
  opacity:0.4
}

.img11{
  width:24px;
  height:24px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top:40px;
  right:95px;
  background: black;
  opacity:0.4
}

.img12{
  width:24px;
  height:24px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top:60px;
  right:50px;
  background: black;
  opacity:0.8
}

.img13{
  width:24px;
  height:24px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top:-10px;
  right:30px;
  background: black;
  opacity:0.8
}

.img14{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top:-5px;
  right:-20px;
  background: black;
  opacity:0.8
}

.img15{
  width:18px;
  height:18px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top:25px;
  right:30px;
  background: black;
  opacity:0.4
}

.img16{
  width:12px;
  height:12px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top:45px;
  right:10px;
  background: black;
  opacity:0.4
}
```

```html
<div class="ripple">
 <h2>
  Explore tribe with us
  </h2>
  <div class="inner">  
  </div>
  <div class="img">
  
  </div>
    <div class="img1">
  
  </div>
  
     <div class="img2">
  
  </div>
      <div class="img3">
  
  </div>
      <div class="img4">
  
  </div>
        <div class="img5">
  
  </div>
        <div class="img6">
  
  </div>
        <div class="img7">
  
  </div>
        <div class="img8">
  
  </div>
        <div class="img9">
  
  </div>
        <div class="img10">
  
  </div>
  
        <div class="img11">
  
  </div>
        <div class="img12">
  
  </div>
        <div class="img13">
  
  </div>
        <div class="img14">
  
  </div>
        <div class="img15">
  
  </div>
        <div class="img16">
  
  </div>
        <div class="img17">
  
  </div>
        <div class="img18">
  
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Is there any way so i can control the shadow. or any other approach also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As inner does not have meaning other than a visual clue you could remove it and instead put those circles onto the ripple element as part of its background.

This snippet does this by putting a radial-gradient as the background image on ripple.

Obviously you'll want to play with the transparency levels and sizes to get exactly the effect you want.

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.ripple {
  width: 400px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #ff8895 0 70px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 70px 100px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100px 125px, transparent 125px 100%);
}

h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.img {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 5px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5
}

.img1 {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 25px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.3
}

.img2 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 5px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.8
}

.img3 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 45px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.2
}

.img4 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 55px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.2
}

.img5 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: 60px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.8
}

.img6 {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 90px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.4
}

.img7 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 80px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.8
}

.img8 {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 150px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.4
}

.img9 {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 210px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.4
}

.img10 {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 140px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.4
}

.img11 {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 95px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.4
}

.img12 {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: 50px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.8
}

.img13 {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: 30px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.8
}

.img14 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: -20px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.8
}

.img15 {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 30px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.4
}

.img16 {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  right: 10px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.4
}
```

```html
<div class="ripple">
  <h2>
    Explore tribe with us
  </h2>
  <div class="img">

  </div>
  <div class="img1">

  </div>

  <div class="img2">

  </div>
  <div class="img3">

  </div>
  <div class="img4">

  </div>
  <div class="img5">

  </div>
  <div class="img6">

  </div>
  <div class="img7">

  </div>
  <div class="img8">

  </div>
  <div class="img9">

  </div>
  <div class="img10">

  </div>

  <div class="img11">

  </div>
  <div class="img12">

  </div>
  <div class="img13">

  </div>
  <div class="img14">

  </div>
  <div class="img15">

  </div>
  <div class="img16">

  </div>
  <div class="img17">

  </div>
  <div class="img18">

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks mathe this will surely help me.